# Spock iteration index in expect: or when: block during test execution

Tags: spock

Consider a test below:

```
@Unroll
def 'demo test'() {
     expect:
          methodTest(inp) == res 
     where:
          inp || res
          "a" || true
          "b" || false 
}
```

This test may result:

```
demo test[0]
demo test[1]
```

My question, is there any way to get those iteration index during test execution? More clearly, while the first test is executing then I would like to get the index 0 in expect: or when: block?

Not sure when and how Spock actually assigns those iteration indexes.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you can't infer an iteration number from Spock. As [Deon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4898433/deon) mentioned, Spock creates different specifications based on your **where** block.

It your really need to know an index you can write it explicitly in the **where** block:

```
where:
idx | inp || res
0   | "a" || true
1   | "b" || false
```

If you just want to know your actual arguments you can include them into the method name:

```
@Unroll
def "demo test: result should be #res if inp=#inp"() {
    expect:
    methodTest(inp) == res 

    where:
    inp || res
    "a" || true
    "b" || false 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of the where clause is that spock doesn't iterate over the options in where, it creates a separate test for each one.

Comment: My understanding is also same as yours except the fact that Spock refers feature method execution of each line of the data table row as iteration of the method.